# How do I calculate the sizes of data types such as blob, map<text,text> in Cassandra?

Tags: types, cassandra

I want to get average size of a cell which has a datatype of blob, map<text,text> or list.

```
uuid: 16 bytes
timeuuid: 16 bytes
timestamp: 8 bytes
bigint: 8 bytes
counter: 8 bytes
double: 8 bytes
time: 8 bytes
inet: 4 bytes (IPv4) or 16 bytes (IPV6)
date: 4 bytes
float: 4 bytes
int 4 bytes
smallint: 2 bytes
tinyint: 1 byte
boolean: 1 byte (hopefully.. no source for this)
ascii: equires an estimate of average # chars * 1 byte/char
text/varchar: requires an estimate of average # chars * (avg. # bytes/char for language)
map/list/set/blob: an estimate
```

I found above sizes from a question posted here earlier. But I want to find an example on how to estimate for types such as text/varchar/map/list/set/blob.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a direct way of calculating the size of CQL `text` or `blob` types because they are not fixed-size columns in the same way that fields are in relational databases.

You can only estimate them based on the amount of data you've stored in a column. For example, the CQL `text` type is a UTF-8 encoded string so a column with a 4-character value is 4 bytes in size. Cheers!